# Why can't I get the value of this text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

It seems simple enough, but nothing I try is working. I have a jquery ui datepicker, I use val() to get the value of that input on button click(), then log it. The click event is working. I can log a string I write myself, but when I pass console.log() the variable that stores the datepicker value...nothing. I've tried using html() and text() instead of val(), still nothing

```
//JS

 $(function(){

    $("button").button();
    $("#date").datepicker();

  var date = $("#date").val();

    $("button").click(function(){

// this logs
  console.log("event working");    

// but this logs nothing

        console.log(date);


    });//close click

});//closes function

//HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.8.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://myDomain/bn/lbStyle.css"/>
<script src="http://myDomain/index.js"></script>

        <title>
            Welcome to The Bringer Network
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="dialog">

        <p>Date <input type="text" id="date"/></p>

         <button>Submit</button>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with commenting your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do. But I think you should place this: `var date = $("#date").val();` in your `click` event. Because your code assigns the `.val()` of the field when it's empty. That's why your `var date` is empty.

http://jsfiddle.net/FnGmS/ - Here is a working demo of this code:

```
$(function () {
    $("button").button();
    $("#date").datepicker();
    $("button").click(function () {
        var date = $("#date").val();
        console.log("event working");
        console.log(date);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should declare date variable within click if you want to assign the value of input field. Go through code below. You actually initialized soon after the page is loaded whixh is not the correct way in your case.

```
$(function(){

    $("button").button();
    $("#date").datepicker();



    $("button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var date = $("#date").val();// look this line. It should be inside.
        console.log("event working");   
        console.log(date);
    });//close click

});
```